# html entities/escape for dynamic url (ajax updated url)?

Tags: regex, html-entities

```
var fb_ps_page = window.location.href;
document.write('<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=' + fb_ps_page + '&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21&amp;appId=205223179497882" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>');
```

My function to write the dynamic url to facebook like button.

But, my url contains `/`, `#`, `+`, and `&` - do I need to escape these, and would I do that using regex?

Comment: Be careful about allowing hashes (#) in URLs that will be liked,  You will need to do canonical URLs to be shared.

Comment: really? even by using html entities for the #?

Comment: Facebook's linter wont be able to get the correct content since all it relies upon is the raw original HTML send down from the server and since it doesn't run javascript.

Comment: @DMCS - should I be doing this with FBML?

Comment: No FBML is deprecated.  However, I do recommend the HTML5 format even over XFBML. FYI FBML != XFBML. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inserting into the URL context, so use proper URL encoding first:

```
document.write('<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=' + encodeURIComponent(fb_ps_page) + '&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21&amp;appId=205223179497882" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>');
```

As `encodeURIComponent` does already encode the HTML special chars `"`, `&`, and `<` (`/`, `#`, and `+` too), you don’t need need to encode it for the HTML context any more.

Comment: yeah, I am not processing today. I completely figured it out about 5 seconds after this post.Thanks for the help.