# Add # and ! to URL plus text from submitted search form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, get

I need submitted text added to a URL from a search from. I found some code here [Add text to parameter before sumbit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17899945/add-text-to-parameter-before-sumbit-form) , which partially works but some of the text I need added includes #! and ? which translates to %23%21 and %3F when added to the url.

Code from stack overflow (best answer):

```
<form action="http://example.com/search" method="get" onsubmit="return addText();">
        <input type="text" name="q" id="q">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <script>
    function addText(){
        document.getElementById("q").value += " BBBB CCCC"; // Whatever your value is
        return true;
    }
    </script>
```

My URL needs to return something like this:

```
http://example.com/?search=TEXT#!summaryList?skipMake=true&skipModel=true
```

The url up to TEXT comes through (TEXT is the q value submitted from the form), but the #! before summary and ? before skip do not and the whole string is needed for the URL to function correctly.

Is there an easy way to make it work using the code above or would I be better off finding a PHP script?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [html entities/escape for dynamic url (ajax updated url)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023983/html-entities-escape-for-dynamic-url-ajax-updated-url)

Answer (score 0):

Use `encodeURIComponent()` to encode your URL (to format `#`):

```
encodeURIComponent(myUrl)
```

Use `decodeURIComponent()` to decode your URL:

```
decodeURIComponent(myUrl)
```

```js
var myUrl = 'search=TEXT#!summaryList?skipMake=true&skipModel=true';
    
console.log('Encode URL', encodeURIComponent(myUrl));
console.log('Decode URL', decodeURIComponent(myUrl));
```

Answer (score 0):

Anything after `#` is not sent to the server. If you need to send it to the server, you will need to place it in it's own parameter (I used `extra` as the name). You will then need to also make sure that it is encoded properly, otherwise it could send that data as key/value as well.

```
http://example.com/?search=TEXT&extra=summaryList%3FskipMake%3Dtrue%26skipModel%3Dtrue
```

On your server side, you will then need to [decode it](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php), and grab the key/value pairs